# Create Java console inside a GUI panel

Tags: java, user-interface, console, output, panel

How can I create an instance of the Java console inside of a GUI panel?

Comment: Do you mean "The java console" the one that provides information about the applets and JNLP applications in use?

Answer (score 77):

Here's a functioning class.  You can install an instance of this into the system out and err using:

```
PrintStream con=new PrintStream(new TextAreaOutputStream(...));
System.setOut(con);
System.setErr(con);
```

**Updated 2014-02-19**: To use EventQueue.invokeLater() to avoid GUI threading issues which can crop up very rarely with the original.

**Updated 2014-02-27**: Better implementation

**Updated 2014-03-25**: Correct recording & deletion of lines in text area to be within the `run()` method to avoid race-condition between appending and deleting which can happen if the console is flooded with output. The end result seems cleaner to me, as well.

**Updated 2022-11-07**: Further improve implementation to completely eliminate problems from flooding with output. Note that this version will outright suppress output (with a one-line note) when it is overwhelmed with output. Previous version would eventually begin GC thrashing and the VM response would largely freeze (without actually crashing) until it finally managed to catch up.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextAreaOutputStream
extends OutputStream
{

// *************************************************************************************************
// INSTANCE PROPERTIES
// *************************************************************************************************

private byte[]                          oneByte;                                                    // array for write(int val);
private Appender                        appender;                                                   // most recent action

// *************************************************************************************************
// INSTANCE CONSTRUCTORS/INIT/CLOSE/FINALIZE
// *************************************************************************************************

public TextAreaOutputStream(JTextArea txtara) {
    this(txtara,1000);
    }

public TextAreaOutputStream(JTextArea txtara, int maxlin) {
    this(txtara,maxlin,null);
    }

public TextAreaOutputStream(JTextArea txtara, int maxlin, Pattern rmvptn) {
    if(maxlin<1) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("TextAreaOutputStream maximum lines must be positive (value="+maxlin+")"); }
    oneByte=new byte[1];
    appender=new Appender(txtara,maxlin,rmvptn);
    }

// *************************************************************************************************
// INSTANCE METHODS - ACCESSORS
// *************************************************************************************************

/** Clear the current console text area. */
public synchronized void clear() {
    if(appender!=null) { appender.clear(); }
    }

// *************************************************************************************************
// INSTANCE METHODS - OUTPUT STREAM IMPLEMENTATION
// *************************************************************************************************

public synchronized void close() {
    appender=null;
    }

public synchronized void flush() {
    }

public synchronized void write(int val) {
    oneByte[0]=(byte)val;
    write(oneByte,0,1);
    }

public synchronized void write(byte[] ba) {
    write(ba,0,ba.length);
    }

public synchronized void write(byte[] ba,int str,int len) {
    if(appender!=null) { appender.append(bytesToString(ba,str,len)); }
    }

// *************************************************************************************************
// INSTANCE METHODS - UTILITY
// *************************************************************************************************

@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings("DM_DEFAULT_ENCODING")
static private String bytesToString(byte[] ba, int str, int len) {
    try { return new String(ba,str,len,"UTF-8"); } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException thr) { return new String(ba,str,len); } // all JVMs are required to support UTF-8
    }

// *************************************************************************************************
// STATIC NESTED CLASSES
// *************************************************************************************************

    static class Appender
    implements Runnable
    {
    private final StringBuilder         line    = new StringBuilder(1000);                                              // current line being assembled
    private final List<String>          lines   = new ArrayList<String>();                                              // lines waiting to be appended
    private final LinkedList<Integer>   lengths = new LinkedList<Integer>();                                            // lengths of each line within text area

    private final JTextArea             textArea;
    private final int                   maxLines;                                                                       // maximum lines allowed in text area
    private final Pattern               rmvPattern;

    private boolean                     clear;
    private boolean                     queue;
    private boolean                     wrapped;

    Appender(JTextArea txtara, int maxlin, Pattern rmvptn) {
        textArea    = txtara;
        maxLines    = maxlin;
        rmvPattern  = rmvptn;

        clear       = false;
        queue       = true;
        wrapped     = false;
        }

    synchronized void append(String val) {
        boolean eol                     = val.endsWith(EOL1) || val.endsWith(EOL2);

        line.append(val);
        while(line.length()>LINE_MAX) {
            emitLine(line.substring(0,LINE_MAX)+EOL1);
            line.replace(0,LINE_MAX,"[>>] ");
            }
        if(eol) {
            emitLine(line.toString());
            line.setLength(0);
            }
        }

    private void emitLine(String lin) {
        if(lines.size()>10_000) {
            lines.clear();
            lines.add("<console-overflowed>\n");
            }
        else {
            if(rmvPattern!=null) { lin = rmvPattern.matcher(lin).replaceAll(""); }
            lines.add(lin);
            }
        if(queue) {
            queue=false;
            EventQueue.invokeLater(this);
            }
        }

    synchronized void clear() {
        clear = true;
        if(queue) { queue = false; EventQueue.invokeLater(this); }
        wrapped = false;
        }

    // MUST BE THE ONLY METHOD THAT TOUCHES textArea!
    public synchronized void run() {
        int                             don = 0;

        if(clear) {
            lengths     . clear();
            lines       . clear();
            textArea    . setText("");
            clear       = false;
            }

        for(String lin: lines) {
            don += 1;
            lengths.addLast(lin.length());
            if(lengths.size()>=maxLines) { textArea.replaceRange("",0,lengths.removeFirst()); }
            textArea.append(lin);
            if(don>=100) { break; }
            }
        if(don==lines.size()) {
            lines.clear();
            queue = true;
            }
        else {
            lines.subList(0,don).clear();
            EventQueue.invokeLater(this);
            }
        }

    static private final String         EOL1        = "\n";
    static private final String         EOL2        = System.getProperty("line.separator",EOL1);
    static private final int            LINE_MAX    = 1000;
}
```

And here's a screenshot of it in action:

[image]

Comment: this have less code: http://unserializableone.blogspot.com/2009/01/redirecting-systemout-and-systemerr-to.html

Comment: @timaschew: Of course it has less code, because it does less. Look at mine a little closer and you'll see it controls the amount of text in the output text pane so it doesn't just fill continuously and crash with an OOM. And it handles exceptions. And it's a self-contained class.

Comment: @timaschew: Also, that simple solution will flood the `EDT` if enough output is thrown at it. Try running something that generates a *lot* of output continuously and in quick succession and watch what happens to the GUI.

Comment: I'm amazed you edited this 6 years later. And I also want to thank you!

Comment: +1. Thank you for the well-thought-out answer. Just one note: it would be probably better to use Java's own [*SuppressWarnings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) annotation instead of some custom *@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings* to avoid confusion.

Comment: @informatik01: Yes; this is old code using FindBugs which predated the annotations (I believe FindBugs now does, but haven't had time to check).

Comment: If like me you want to rely on another swing component instead of a `JTextArea`, here is a flexible code for doing so: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27737289/363573

Comment: This is perfect. But I do have a lot of log and it only shows up after 20 seconds. Is ther any way to speed up log output?

Comment: @Jefeinfiltrado : That suggests your EDT is flooded, or some other similar bottleneck. You'll need to analyze what's going on with memory, etc.

Comment: I like that you took RAM into consideration, +1

Answer (score 25):

@Sofware Monkey:

It works! :)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main( String [] args ) throws InterruptedException  {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add( new JLabel(" Outout" ), BorderLayout.NORTH );

        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
        TextAreaOutputStream taos = new TextAreaOutputStream( ta, 60 );
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream( taos );
        System.setOut( ps );
        System.setErr( ps );


        frame.add( new JScrollPane( ta )  );

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
        frame.setSize(800,600);

        for( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ ) {
            System.out.println( i );
            Thread.sleep( 500 );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If helps for anything. I've mark this as community wiki. At least I won't get points for something I didn't program.

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is an old thread but the fact that I found it while trying to figure out a good way of doing this means others probably will too.

Here's a (Probably) cleaner way of doing what software monkey posted:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/**
 * Represents a console viewable through a <code>JTextArea</code>.
 * 
 * <p>
 *  Implementation:
 *  <code>
 *      System.setOut(new PrintStream(new Console( ... )));
 *  </code>
 *  </p>
 * 
 * @author Derive McNeill
 *
 */
public class Console extends OutputStream {

    /**
     * Represents the data written to the stream.
     */
    ArrayList <Byte> data = new ArrayList <Byte> ();

    /**
     * Represents the text area that will be showing the written data.
     */
    private JTextArea output;

    /**
     * Creates a console context.
     * @param output
     *      The text area to output the consoles text.
     */
    public Console(JTextArea output) {
        this.output = output;
    }

    /**
     * Called when data has been written to the console.
     */
    private void fireDataWritten() {

        // First we loop through our written data counting the lines.
        int lines = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            byte b = data.get(i);

            // Specifically we look for 10 which represents "\n".
            if (b == 10) {
                lines++;
            }

            // If the line count exceeds 250 we remove older lines.
            if (lines >= 250) {
                data = (ArrayList<Byte>) data.subList(i, data.size());
            }
        }

        // We then create a string builder to append our text data.
        StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder();

        // We loop through the text data appending it to the string builder.
        for (byte b : data) {
            bldr.append((char) b);
        }

        // Finally we set the outputs text to our built string.
        output.setText(bldr.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int i) throws IOException {

        // Append the piece of data to our array of data.
        data.add((byte) i);

        // Indicate that data has just been written.
        fireDataWritten();
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work; the text area is directly accessed via `fireDataWritten` by whatever thread does the write, which is not guaranteed to be the EDT.

Comment: Also, this will have exponentially worse performance as more data is added to the text area such that more and more bytes will have to be converted to a string, and then set into the text area. Not a great characteristic for a GUI console (which may easily have 10's of MiB of data in it). Making this worse, it creates one `Byte` object for every byte written. And it repopulates the text area for every byte written.

Answer (score 2):

[ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) can be used to omit buffering stuff.

```
private void redirectConsoleTo(final JTextArea textarea) {
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream() {
        public synchronized void flush() throws IOException {
            textarea.setText(toString());
        }
    }, true);

    System.setErr(out);
    System.setOut(out);
}
```

Rather than limiting line number, you can bind [ByteArrayOutputStream#reset()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#reset%28%29) to some button.

```
private void redirectConsoleWithClearButton(final JTextArea textarea, JButton clearButton) {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream() {
        public synchronized void flush() throws IOException {
            textarea.setText(toString());
        }
    };

    clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            bytes.reset();
        }
    });

    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(bytes, true);

    System.setErr(out);
    System.setOut(out);
}
```

Comment: This accesses the text area off the EDT, which, as I found out, will eventually cause a deadlock in the GUI.

Comment: Also, this will have exponentially worse performance as more data is added to the text area such that more and more bytes will have to be converted to a string, and then set into the text area. Not a great characteristic for a GUI console (which may easily have 10's of MiB of data in it).

Answer (score 2):

I recently use the [excellent code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/343007/363573) provided by [Lawrence Dol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/343007/363573) in one of my project.

However, in my case the code consumed too many memory. I managed to reduce drastically the memory comsuption by replacing `JTextarea` by a `JLabel`.

My memory saving searches showed that `JTextarea` internal code tends to hold the actual text sent too much time. Consequently, all this text could not be garbage collected.

Here is the flexible version of initial code (with thread synchronization replaced by locks).

### JComponentOutputStream.java

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class JComponentOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    // *************************************************************************************************
    // INSTANCE MEMBERS
    // *************************************************************************************************

    private byte[] oneByte; // array for write(int val);
    private Appender appender; // most recent action

    private Lock jcosLock = new ReentrantLock();

    public JComponentOutputStream(JComponent txtara, JComponentHandler handler) {
        this(txtara, 1000, handler);
    }

    public JComponentOutputStream(JComponent txtara, int maxlin, JComponentHandler handler) {
        if (maxlin < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("JComponentOutputStream maximum lines must be positive (value=" + maxlin + ")");
        }
        oneByte = new byte[1];
        appender = new Appender(txtara, maxlin, handler);
    }

    /** Clear the current console text area. */
    public void clear() {
        jcosLock.lock();
        try {
            if (appender != null) {
                appender.clear();
            }
        } finally {
            jcosLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        jcosLock.lock();
        try {
            appender = null;
        } finally {
            jcosLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void flush() {
        // sstosLock.lock();
        // try {
        // // TODO: Add necessary code here...
        // } finally {
        // sstosLock.unlock();
        // }
    }

    public void write(int val) {
        jcosLock.lock();
        try {
            oneByte[0] = (byte) val;
            write(oneByte, 0, 1);
        } finally {
            jcosLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void write(byte[] ba) {
        jcosLock.lock();
        try {
            write(ba, 0, ba.length);
        } finally {
            jcosLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void write(byte[] ba, int str, int len) {
        jcosLock.lock();
        try {
            if (appender != null) {
                appender.append(bytesToString(ba, str, len));
            }
        } finally {
            jcosLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    static private String bytesToString(byte[] ba, int str, int len) {
        try {
            return new String(ba, str, len, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException thr) {
            return new String(ba, str, len);
        } // all JVMs are required to support UTF-8
    }

    // *************************************************************************************************
    // STATIC MEMBERS
    // *************************************************************************************************

    static class Appender implements Runnable {
        private final JComponent swingComponent;
        private final int maxLines; // maximum lines allowed in text area
        private final LinkedList<Integer> lengths; // length of lines within
                                                    // text area
        private final List<String> values; // values waiting to be appended

        private int curLength; // length of current line
        private boolean clear;
        private boolean queue;

        private Lock appenderLock;

        private JComponentHandler handler;

        Appender(JComponent cpt, int maxlin, JComponentHandler hndlr) {
            appenderLock = new ReentrantLock();

            swingComponent = cpt;
            maxLines = maxlin;
            lengths = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            values = new ArrayList<String>();

            curLength = 0;
            clear = false;
            queue = true;

            handler = hndlr;
        }

        void append(String val) {
            appenderLock.lock();
            try {
                values.add(val);
                if (queue) {
                    queue = false;
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(this);
                }
            } finally {
                appenderLock.unlock();
            }
        }

        void clear() {
            appenderLock.lock();
            try {

                clear = true;
                curLength = 0;
                lengths.clear();
                values.clear();
                if (queue) {
                    queue = false;
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(this);
                }
            } finally {
                appenderLock.unlock();
            }
        }

        // MUST BE THE ONLY METHOD THAT TOUCHES the JComponent!
        public void run() {
            appenderLock.lock();
            try {
                if (clear) {
                    handler.setText(swingComponent, "");
                }
                for (String val : values) {
                    curLength += val.length();
                    if (val.endsWith(EOL1) || val.endsWith(EOL2)) {
                        if (lengths.size() >= maxLines) {
                            handler.replaceRange(swingComponent, "", 0, lengths.removeFirst());
                        }
                        lengths.addLast(curLength);
                        curLength = 0;
                    }
                    handler.append(swingComponent, val);
                }

                values.clear();
                clear = false;
                queue = true;
            } finally {
                appenderLock.unlock();
            }
        }

        static private final String EOL1 = "\n";
        static private final String EOL2 = System.getProperty("line.separator", EOL1);
    }

    public interface JComponentHandler {
        void setText(JComponent swingComponent, String text);

        void replaceRange(JComponent swingComponent, String text, int start, int end);

        void append(JComponent swingComponent, String text);
    }

} /* END PUBLIC CLASS */
```

---

### Sample usage

```
JLabel console = new JLabel();
JComponentOutputStream consoleOutputStream = new JComponentOutputStream(console, new JComponentHandler() {
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    public void setText(JComponent swingComponent, String text) {
        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        append(swingComponent, text);
    }

    @Override
    public void replaceRange(JComponent swingComponent, String text, int start, int end) {
        sb.replace(start, end, text);
        redrawTextOf(swingComponent);
    }

    @Override
    public void append(JComponent swingComponent, String text) {
        sb.append(text);
        redrawTextOf(swingComponent);
    }

    private void redrawTextOf(JComponent swingComponent) {
        ((JLabel)swingComponent).setText("<html><pre>" + sb.toString() + "</pre></html>");
    }
});

PrintStream con = new PrintStream(consoleOutputStream);
System.setOut(con);
System.setErr(con);    

// Optional: add a scrollpane around the console for having scrolling bars
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane( //
        console, //
        ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, //
        ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED //
);
myPanel.add(sp);
```