# How to embed a mini-console within a Java app?

Tags: java

I'm making a small game in Java and would like to add a Quake 3 style of console to the game, that supposed to appear when toggled.  Is there any implementation or any similar embedded console you folks know of?

Otherwise, what would be a good way to go about it?  Right now, I simply have a TextArea on top of a TextField.  Just to clarify, I'm not looking for a full fledged terminal, what I need is a small little console that I can tie with the game.

Comment: I'm sorry but bad grammar bugs me; "is there was" is horrible.

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you already have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342990/create-java-console-inside-the-panel/343007#343007) to [this other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342990/create-java-console-inside-the-panel).  I believe it answers your question.

Comment: That was the one I was looking for.