# Display CMD output in my GUI (java)

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, cmd, real-time

How might I get the output from a CMD process to display in my GUI?  This is the code I'm using to run the process:

```
try {
    String line;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"e:\\folder\\someCommands.cmd\"");
    BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    input.close();
} catch (Exception err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've tried doing this:

```
jLabel1.setText(line);
```

...but the GUI is completely locked up while the process is running, so nothing updates until the very end, which isn't very useful.  Other than that the CMD works fine.  I just want to display the output in real-time.

Comment: This answer from ["Software Monkey"](http://stackoverflow.com/users/8946/software-monkey) should do: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342990/create-java-console-inside-the-panel>

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use JLabel rather and JTextArea?

Comment: Suggest removing real-time tag from this question. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time for a definition of real-time computing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you repaint() after setting the text of the label?

Anyway, you should generally be hesitant to execute a long operation on the GUI event thread. Look into using a [`SwingWorker`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) instead.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to start a separate thread to run the process. The code you're using to run it can mostly just be inserted into the thread's (or `Runnable`'s) `run()` method as is, but to set the text in the JLabel, you should use something like this:

```
...
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SetTextRunnable(jLabel1, line));
}
...

class SetTextRunnable implements Runnable {
    private String line;
    private JLabel jLabel1
    public SetTextRunnable(JLabel jLabel1, String line) {
        this.jLabel1 = jLabel1;
        this.line = line;
    }
    public void run() {
        jLabel1.setText(line);
    }
}
```

*EDIT*: just noticed something: apparently the class `SwingWorker` was designed for this sort of thing, so that's another option for you (if it exists in your version of Java).

*EDIT to the EDIT*: so silly me, I didn't notice `SwingWorker` was already mentioned in another answer.

Comment: or just put the code to read the process' stream into a separate thread. For example, you might want another thread that reads the error stream.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others have said about multithreading this - you'll also want to read the child process error stream.  I believe that (in some instances) if you don't drain the error stream for the process it could cause it to hang.