# Java - How to enter runtime arguments (of main method) by double-clicking a jar file?

Tags: java

I encountered this problem several times. If I pack a Java application in an executable jar file that takes arguments from a user, then the user have to invoke the program (jar file) from the command prompt by the following command:

```
java -jar "jar-file-name.jar"
```

But I want that whenever a user double clicks on the executable jar file (that needs arguments from the user), a window (command-prompt window) appears that would appear if we had invoked the jar file from the command-prompt.

I know one solution to this is using batch file `.bat` to run the jar file. Is there any other solution?

Comment: switch to GUI application which pops up a screen for params?

Comment: @Fakrudeen: Kindly suggest only those answers that are relevant to the question... I am not asking about the ways to get input from a user... I am asking a question that is focused on a particular thing... so before answering first read the question thoroughly...

Comment: Kindly check your attitude at the door... people on this site are volunteering their time to help you.  Maybe the answers and suggestions are not exactly what you're looking for, but maybe they'll give you an idea you hadn't thought of on your own... after all that's why you're here, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To explain why:

There are 2 java JVM exe launchers:

- java.exe: console based - provides console input/output.
- javaw.exe: for GUI apps - hides the console.

JAR file extensions are associated with javaw.exe by default, which is why you don't get a console when you double-click them.

The answers others have given, and adding my own:

- rewrite your app so that it uses Java GUI items for input and output instead of System.in/System.out. This may be over-complex for what you require.
- You mentioned creating a batch file so that the console-based Java JVM (java.exe) is run, You could also create a windows shortcut specifying the command line: `java -jar  jar-file-name.jar`
- You could change the windows file associations for .jar (but generally this is a bad idea -- new Java installs may reset this, and it will mean all java apps run from jars will have a console)
- You could use a Java launcher like [WinRun4J](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/) which allows you to simply drop a double-clickable EXE with an icon and a config file that specifies how your app should be run (with/without console, and with any other JVM and command line parameters )

Personally I went for the last option in my project - I made my jar file non-executable, and the user has to double-click the EXE. It also allowed me to specify a nice icon for my project, and provide multiple options on launch (debug/non-debug mode)  simply by having a different exe/config file.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to reassign the explorer association for ".jar" to java.exe instead of javaw.exe.  This is somewhat of a questionable thing to do - it might make more sense to create your console output window.  You can, of course, trivially pop up a dialog for user input of required execution parameters if they are not supplied on the command line.

There is working code for a console output JTextArea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342990/create-java-console-inside-the-panel/343007#343007).

Comment: Note that the user wants console input, as well as possibly console output.

Comment: @Panda: True, that was not immediately clear from the question.

Comment: It is clearly stated that I want my user to input runtime arguments... I don't think that there is anything unclear in the question...

Answer (score 0):

This is an operating system feature.

If you want full control, then you must provide this functionality inside your program (or with a wrapper class.