# logging data using log4j into a TextArea is there an easy way to do this

Tags: java, log4j

I am logging messages via log 4 j logger and I want to somehow get this stream of data and display it in a JTextArea for display. Is there any easy way to do this?

thanks you

Comment: you may want to write your own/custom appender, have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072389/how-to-create-a-own-appender-in-log4j)

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it myself, but most straight-forward way would be to implement `org.apache.log4j.Appender`, so your implementation's constructor would accept instance of GUI object where you want to show log entries.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out here for solution and suggestion as well [jtextarea-as-listener-for-log4j-logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349196/jtextarea-as-listener-for-log4j-logger) . I hope it's helpful.