# Output Program in GUI instead of CLI

Tags: java, user-interface, command-line-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [create java console inside the panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342990/create-java-console-inside-the-panel)

So, I have a simple program that only consists of input, computations and output. Instead of displaying the prompts, computations and results in the command line (output) of the IDE, I was hoping to embed it on another program. Maybe on a GUI item, like a text area or anything that pops up.

Are there any GUI elements that are suited for this purpose? Thanks!

Comment: Yeap, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342990/create-java-console-inside-the-panel

Comment: But I think this would not work when input is expected

Answer (score 1):

you can try using Java Swing which will help you build the UI in simple drag and drop

Comment: thanks, are there any particular containers suitable for this?

Comment: depends on what you want to output. For example if you only have simple calculations, you can use only jTextfield to accept input, and labels to show output.

Comment: and all of that could be put in a jFrame or jPanel? maybe

Comment: i was hoping to get the same feel as the console. An exact console, but in a GUI, like a big textarea where all inputs and outputs take place. Not sure if there is actually such a thing.