# How do I get this to run. I keep on getting a cannot find symbol

Tags: java, user-interface

I saw this code on this stackoverflow question at [Create Java console inside a GUI panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342990/create-java-console-inside-the-panel/343007#343007)

Whenever I compile the code though I get an error saying it can't find the symbol TextAreaOutputStream. I really want to have this work. I would really appreciate an explanation for why I can't compile this.

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.io.*;

public class GUI{
public static void main( String [] args ) throws InterruptedException  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add( new JLabel(" Outout" ), BorderLayout.NORTH );

    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
    TextAreaOutputStream taos = new TextAreaOutputStream( ta, 60 );
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream( taos );
    System.setOut( ps );
    System.setErr( ps );


    frame.add( new JScrollPane( ta )  );

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible( true );

    for( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ ) {
        System.out.println( i );
        Thread.sleep( 500 );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to import this class like the other imports above

Comment: Are you sure that you have imported it?

Comment: Do you know which class it is because I thought it was included in java.io.*?

Comment: No its a custom class see the answer code of that question.

Comment: What's with the practice of not indenting methods in a class?  I've noticed it a couple of times over the last few days, and your post inspired me to ask.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Probably just easier to indent the outer code to get an SO code block than to select the text in an editor, move it over, etc.

Comment: That's not actually how my code looks in a text editor. That's just the easiest way for me to make it look in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

TextAreaOutputStream isn't a class included in the standard library. The code for it is in that other SO post you referenced. To use it, you'll have to copy/paste that code and compile it along with your class. You might be better off looking around for an existing library that does what you want.

Comment: Downvote? What in particular do you find wrong with this answer?