# How can I create a java GUI so when I double click a .jar it launches a java GUI that acts like a console

Tags: java, user-interface

I have some code that requires input and output and I want to make this into a .jar file that when double clicked can launch a GUI console like application that will work with my code.

The closest I've been able to find is this
[Create Java console inside a GUI panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342990/create-java-console-inside-the-panel/343007#343007)
But this doesn't really help because I also want the user to be able to input.

Lets say I have this code below

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Name {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
                String name = x.nextLine();
                System.out.println(name);
          }
    }
```

I want this to be able to be run in a console like environment but through a java GUI so I can use a .jar file. And please don't recommend a batch file because that is not what I'm looking for.

For the code above here is exactly what I want. I want to be able to have this work exactly how it would normally when double clicked on as a batch file. Except I want it to be executed from a .jar file so I could just double click that and launch it from a mac or a pc in any directory.

Comment: Why? Why try to force a console like application in an event-driven GUI rather than pure event-driven goodness?

Comment: Huh? You can create a GUI with a .jar file.

Comment: @SLaks: unless I'm misreading the question, I don't think that that is the issue. To me it seems like he wants to create a GUI that behaves as a console which seems a little odd to me.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: You may be right; it's a very unclear question.  However, his mention of a batch file implies that I'm right.  Either way, it sounds weird.

Comment: If you look at the link to another SO question I provided it might clear it up a little bit. The only problem with that one though is it doesn't let me change the input's standard behavior only the outputs.

Comment: Use a JTextField for input.  It can be placed just below the JTextArea /output window by way of BorderLayout.

Comment: @JDN: What is your ultimate intention? From this ... "I want this to be able to be run in a console like environment but through a java GUI so I can use a .jar file." ... I gather that what you actually want is: Make standard Java console applications that can be started by double-clicking a .jar file. Correct? If so: I just created a Java class that makes this possible. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32547250/3500521