# How do I Redirect the console output of my Java/KDB program to a GUI TextField

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

**Disclaimers:**

> Special KDB knowledge is unneccessary for this.
>   I realise there are some similar questions but none of the solutions have worked for me. I'm in a situation slightly unique to the similar questions you might find on here.
>   I apologize if I've missed any information here you would need. Ask and I'll give you as much info as you need.

I have a Java application with 3 classes, but only 2 are relevant because 3rd is an API created by kx called 'Fusion'.

Basically, the application queries a KDB database which returns the last row of a trade table every second. This table is constantly added modified by a `feed`. I have it return the last row, where I have it to print to the console. But I need it to be printed in a JavaFX `textField` or `textArea` instead. I'm not that great at creating Java GUIs as my job doesn't usually require me to make them. I feel like this is a bit harder than it sounds.

My `ConnectionToKDB` class is responsible for printing to the console but I need to send what it is printing to the GUI in the main class `JavaFXToKDB`. I've been thinking that there must be a way to redirect the console output to the GUI component `textfield` in `JavaFXToKDB.java`.

Another idea is to maybe store the outputs from the flip code to a string array list and make it somehow accessible to the `textfield`. I could really use some advice on this. Also the console printing occurs in the code block where you see me accessing the flip function and accessing `rows` and `columns`. You can find the class for the Fusion API [here](https://github.com/KxSystems/javakdb/blob/master/src/kx/c.java) if you wish to look at the flip function.

#### JavaFxToKDB.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.lang.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;


public class JavaFxToKdb extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TextField textfield = new TextField();
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Show me the last Trade Record");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(textfield,btn);
        vbox.setSpacing(10);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(40,40,40,40));
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 600, 500);

        primaryStage.setTitle("KDB Connector");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);


/*
Instance of the class containing the method which connects to the KDB Process and queries the process table
        */
        ConnectionToKDB varConnect = new ConnectionToKDB();
        //varConnect.ConnectToKDB();
    }



}
```

#### ConnectionToKDB.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class ConnectionToKDB {

    public ConnectionToKDB(){}

   public void ConnectToKDB(){
    //c connection = null;
        // 1) create a java calendar instance
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        // 2) get a java.util.Date from the calendar instance.
        //    this date will represent the current instant, or "now".
        java.util.Date now = calendar.getTime();
        // 3) a java current time (now) instance
        java.sql.Timestamp currentTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(now.getTime());
        try{
        c connection=new c("localhost",6002,"admin:admin");

        boolean run = true; //While true the application will continue to query the kdb process (RDB or TP depending on port)
        while(run){


        //System.out.println("Received "+ Arrays.deepToString(objectFeedArray));
        //System.out.println("Recieved" + connection.k("-1#trade"));

/*
Prints the returned table row with column names and row data
*/
        c.Flip flip = (c.Flip)connection.k("-1#trade");
        for(int col=0;col<flip.x.length;col++)
          System.out.print((col>0?",":"")+flip.x[col]);
        System.out.println();
        for(int row=0;row<c.n(flip.y[0]);row++){
          for(int col=0;col<flip.x.length;col++)
            System.out.print((col>0?",":"")+c.at(flip.y[col],row));
            System.out.println();
        }
        //run = false;
        Thread.sleep(1000); // Prevents duplicate rows produced due to querying the rdb multiple times before a new 'last row' was generated
        //System.out.println(connection.k("2+4")); //Test connection to kdb process
        }
        //connection.close();

        }
        catch(c.KException ke){
            System.out.println("Oops"); 
        }
        catch(IOException io){
            System.out.println("Oops2");
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie){
            System.out.println("Oops3");
        }
        System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: So, what's wrong with doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945537/how-to-set-output-stream-to-textarea/12945678#12945678)?  The solution is decoupled enough that you should be able take the core concept of `StreamCapturer` and it's companion `Consumer` and apply it to your problem

Comment: An over all better solution would be to have `ConnectionToKDB` generate a notification/event when ever it gets new content, then allow observers to react to those events in what ever prescribed manner they want to

Comment: I would also consider using `java.util.Timer` to schedule regular updates, but that's just me

Comment: @MadProgrammer wow i couldnt find that post before, i was probably trying to search too specific. Let me try this and get back to you

Comment: @MadProgrammer the timer would be a cool touch, its just the database updates multiple times a second and i query it faster than it updates so i was getting duplicate rows, so i figure sleeping a second inbetween record prints is ok for now. ill change down the line at some point. I plan to have a button which when pressed will show the latest record recieved from the KDB process

Comment: @cknoxk9 Just beware, you can't update the UI from outside JavaFX's "main" thread, so you'll need to synchronise the updates from your update thread with it

Comment: To get around the threading issues, you could use something like: [Most efficient way to log messages to JavaFX TextArea via threads with simple custom logging frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116858/most-efficient-way-to-log-messages-to-javafx-textarea-via-threads-with-simple-cu).  If it's just about redirecting output and not worrying about threading, also see related: [Redirecting System.out to a TextArea in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841884/redirecting-system-out-to-a-textarea-in-javafx).

Comment: You might want to take a look at [ScheduledService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html) as well.

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks this worked for me! thanks everyone for the helpful comments