# Update jTextArea using System.out when program is running

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

So I've been trying to work with the code in this post [for making a console window in a JTextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342990/create-java-console-inside-the-panel).  That code seems to be functioning with mine, but I'm running into an odd problem.

My program: I'm basically building a quick and dirty gui for a command line tool I made recently.  The only thing that the gui contains is a button that says "Start Automation Engine" and then it has a `JTextArea` that is supposed to display any text my program sends to `System.out.println()`.

At the moment it displays nothing, though the program itself is running and working (and should be displaying output as a result.)  I have noticed that when I click the button on my gui the button stays depressed while the program runs.  This has lead me to believe that the `JFrame` is not updating while the program is running, thus the `JTextArea`, as it's child, is not updating.  This is not so good...

Is there a way to get that `JTextArea` to update while the program is running in the background?

Here's my code for the `JFrame`, btw, if you'd like to look at it to get a better idea of what I'm talking about.  It was mostly constructed in WindowBuilder in Eclipse.  The only thing I did was add a button listener to `startAutmoatorEngineButton` and then add the last few lines of the `initalize()` method to set the `JTextArea` (`engineOutput`) as the `System.out`.

```
public class EngineGUI {

private JFrame frmAutomatorEngine;
private File logPath = new File("<redacted>", "<redacted>");
private File masterFile = new File("<redacted>", "<redacted>");

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                EngineGUI window = new EngineGUI();
                window.frmAutomatorEngine.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public EngineGUI() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frmAutomatorEngine = new JFrame();
    frmAutomatorEngine.setType(Type.UTILITY);
    frmAutomatorEngine.setResizable(false);
    frmAutomatorEngine.setTitle("Automator Engine");
    frmAutomatorEngine.setBounds(100, 100, 636, 335);
    frmAutomatorEngine.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frmAutomatorEngine.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu mnEngine = new JMenu("Engine");
    menuBar.add(mnEngine);

    JMenuItem mntmLoadMasterFile = new JMenuItem("Load Master File...");
    mnEngine.add(mntmLoadMasterFile);

    JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    mnEngine.add(mntmExit);
    frmAutomatorEngine.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JTextArea engineOutput = new JTextArea();
    engineOutput.setBounds(10, 48, 600, 217);
    frmAutomatorEngine.getContentPane().add(engineOutput);

    JButton startAutomatorEngineButton = new JButton("Start Automator Engine");
    startAutomatorEngineButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            MasterFile master = null;
            try {
                master = new MasterFile(masterFile, logPath);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            AutomationLoop theLoop = new AutomationLoop(master);
            theLoop.startLoop();

        }
    });
    startAutomatorEngineButton.setBounds(441, 11, 169, 23);
    frmAutomatorEngine.getContentPane().add(startAutomatorEngineButton);

    //Set up textArea to be used as output stream for program
    TextAreaOutputStream outputStream = new TextAreaOutputStream(engineOutput);
    PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
    System.setOut(printStream);
    //System.setErr(printStream);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell for sure because I don't know what your AutomationLoop and TextAreaOutputStream classes do, but it sounds like a threading problem.

All your Swing code needs to execute in the Event Dispatch Thread. If you have a long running code that is not updating the GUI, then you probably want it running another thread, otherwise the GUI doesn't get a chance to update. From your behavior, it sounds like theLoop.startLoop() is running in the Event Dispatch Thread, and so the GUI never gets a chance to update itself.

Does theLoop.startLoop() start a new thread? If not it probably should; otherwise until that code finishes executing, your GUI will not update.

Comment: No, it doesn't start a new thread...  Do you know of any good tutorials to throw that on another thread?

Comment: You could just try the Oracle/Sun one:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: Yup, you were right.  I made a separate thread to run my loop and now the main window is updating properly.  Thank you very much for the help!