# How do I run a program within a running JPanel or GUI?

Tags: user-interface, real-time, execution

I am trying to execute a simple program, in real-time, WITHIN a GUI window that is already running.

The suggested information is helpful, but not quite what I am looking for. In addition to having the code launched in a console, is there a way to have that console (or GUI) run an outside program? Java or textfile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Java console inside a GUI panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342990/create-java-console-inside-a-gui-panel)

Comment: Thank you!!! After doing some additional research I discovered what I was looking for. I simply didn't know what proper termonology to use initially. Thank you for the responses/answers!