# Can I convert my console Java app into a .jar?

Tags: java, jframe

I have a Java App that runs on my Windows terminal. it uses `scanner` for inputs and `System.out.println()` to display outputs.

When I compile my aplication into a `.jar` file, I need to write a `.bat` file in order to run my app, because there's no UI. I wonder if I can 'emulate' the windows terminal in a `.jar` file, directly. Without needing to create a batch. Just double click and play the game. Input and Output.

Something that might help visualization is the `server.jar`, from Minecraft. In the right corner, there is a console with the logs and so on... But I don't need to create a `.run` batch to run the jar and, if I create one, the outputs will be the exact same of the `.jar` file, when I double click. One thing that I dont know for sure is that inputs, in the `server.jar` are allowed.

I've done some tests with `JFrame` and `System.setOutputStream()`, but I'm lost and don't know what to use or what to do. I'm using netbeans because I think it's easier to implement JFrames and so on... But don't know what elements I should use or where to start.

Comment: Would this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342990/create-java-console-inside-a-gui-panel